# Trouble setting up JNI project on OS X

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've been following this (http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/eclipse_CDT_JNI_MinGW_64bit.php) tutorial for setting up a JNI project for a c++ / java project I'm working on. I've been having some trouble getting it working though. I followed the steps and I'm getting an error when I try to build my makefile: "No classes were specified on the command line. Try -help".

I checked if my path was set in environment and it wasn't, so I set it to /usr/bin. I'm not sure if that's right however, so that may be the issue. Also, when I open my only c++ file, Eclipse doesn't recognize any of the reserved words (all the text is black).

I know my post is a bit vague, but can someone help me figure out what's going on? I'm relatively new to OS X and eclipse so I'm lost. I'll provide any information y'all ask for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. One of the lines in my makefile was incorrect, I was trying to access a nonexistant class file.